# Could not resolve NativeQuery parameter type | Spring Boot update version 3

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm trying to query a *PostgreSQL* database using a native query in *Hibernate*. Unfortunately whenever I try I get the error: **Could not resolve NativeQuery parameter type : org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterPositionalImpl@22**.

That's the query:

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)
@Query(value = "update table_name set column1=?3 where column1=?2 and parameter=?1", nativeQuery = true)
int myQuery(String parameter, Customer oldValue, Customer newValue);
```

Is it dependent on the SQL-Dialect settings in Intellij? I've set it to *Generic SQL*. Has anyone stumbled upon this problem before? Thanks in advice :)

Comment: Do you use Spring?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Spring Boot to be exact.

Comment: please share the complete stacktrace

Comment: The parameter oldValue and newValue should be primitive types, not objects

Comment: That indeed did the trick. Thanks. I saw your comment after posting the answer 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I've got the solution.** The problem occured after the update of Spring Boot to the version 3. It's no longer possible to use the self-made java entities in native queries - **Customer** in this case.

The solution in this case was to replace the Customer entity with just the id of it.