Spring boot 3+ / Hibernate 6.4+ unable to use hibernate entity as a parameter in native queries
Upgrading my spring boot from 2.x to 3.x.  I have a lot native queries, which use the entity as query parameter.  It worked fine in spring boot 2.x but stopped working after upgraded to spring boot 3
For example in this demo native query:
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT o.a from table as o WHERE o.user= :user ORDER BY o.a", nativeQuery = true)

public List<String> nativeFindDistinctShippingMethodByUserOrderByShippingMethod(@Param("user") User user);

It works fine in older spring boot/hibernate.
In Spring boot 3, here is the error:
[ERROR] 2024-08-26 07:26:46.775 [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8002-exec-4] [dispatcherServlet].log() - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Could not resolve NativeQuery parameter type : `org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterNamedImpl@2c0b7d22`] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve NativeQuery parameter type : `org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterNamedImpl@2c0b7d22`
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcParameterBindingsImpl.<init>(JdbcParameterBindingsImpl.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
JdbcParameterBindingsImpl.java:78
    at org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeSelectQueryPlanImpl.performList(NativeSelectQueryPlanImpl.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
NativeSelectQueryPlanImpl.java:126
    at org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:628) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
NativeQueryImpl.java:628


In spring boot 3 I have to change the code to:
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT o.a from table as o WHERE o.user= :user ORDER BY o.a", nativeQuery = true)

public List<String> nativeFindDistinctShippingMethodByUserOrderByShippingMethod(@Param("user") Long userId);

So is there a flag I can turn on so that I can use the old way?  I have many native queries use entity as parameters.
Thanks

Please add relevant stacktrace/logs to your question when using @Param("user") User user

add, thanks a lot!

According to this accepted answer, you'll have to make changes in your code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76522587/14072498. This issue backs it up: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2680

Thanks, I guess I will have to fix that.
